# Uploading ReactJS project on GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I am following the instructions on here: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

When adding a homepage to my pacakge.json file, I tried both of these:
`https://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}`
`https://{username}.github.io`

When I do it with the {repo-name}, I get a white screen. When I try it without the {repo-name}, I'm getting a 404 not found.

Anyone know what the error could be?

Comment: Is it a user site or a project site? Have you read https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages? Is the 404 from GitHub or your app? When you get a white screen, what causes it?

Comment: Check your console for  errors on the white screen page. That's often a sign something blew up early in initializing react (assuming everything published correctly)

Comment: Did you upload a ReactJS project to GH pages? Or a website that uses React as its UI library? I'm not sure I understand what you are tryong to achieve since it makes no sense to upload a project, let alone a ReactJS one: a project is not executable; ReactJS is not a framework.

Comment: The 404 and white screen are GitHub errors. It functions which i run it locally. I uploaded a ReactJS project to GH Pages, yes.